# In VM of Azure, concurrent processing

Tags: azure, concurrency, azure-virtual-machine

In VM of Microsoft Azure,
I want this experiment.

step 1. creating two VM. (vert easy...)
step 2. i want 'concurrent processing'  with one work  on two created VM (want to know..this is possible or impossible.)

in this experiment, i want to know that concurrent processing in VM of Microsoft Azure is possible.
and... if concurrent processing is possible, i want to know a proper work which will be done properly between two VM.

(sorry... i'm not skilful in english...  'a proper work' is whatever will be done in two VM)
(i don't have good thinking about "one work". please advise your thinking of "proper work")

I interst in VM.

But this experiment is merely done in two VM , I have a dream that concurrent processing in many VM with a big work(very big....) will create efficient result(ex- time, speed, precise)

So, i want answer about my question 
1. concurrent processing is possible? impossible?
2. proper work
3. method to try this experiment.

1. and.. ETC ( helpful Web Site URL.....)

please !

whdahek@naver.com

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, based on what I understand from your question, the context of concurrency here is little misleading.

The context of `concurrency` depends on the type of application.

- For the applications like `Web Application` you will deploy 2 or more machines behind a `Load-Balancer`. This ensures, `high availability` and `high throughput` for your entire architecture. The application will be accessed via the load balancer's `URL` or `IP`, behind the scenes, one of the web servers will respond.
- For the applications like `MAP-REDUCE`, 2 or more machines will work simultaneously to crunch or process the task guided by a `MASTER` machine.

**Coming to your question, about the possibility of it in Azure...**

Yes, both of the above are possible. Azure Virtual Machines has nothing to do with possibility of the above scenarios, it purely on how your manage and architect your application.